# AngularJS: access Array within $resource object

Tags: arrays, angularjs, rest, resources

My oracle REST-API returns an JSON with an array of tupels from a databese table.
I am using the `$resource` API of angularJs to access the data, so my result looks like this:

```
Resource {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false}
 $promise:Promise {$$state: {…}}
 $resolved: true
 count: 25
 hasMore: true
 items: Array(25)
0:{metricavgcount: 0, instid: 1, metric: "SQL Service Response Time", unit: "CentiSeconds Per Call", threshold: 3, …}
1:{metricavgcount: 1, instid: 1, metric: "Physical Reads Per Sec", unit: "Reads Per Second", threshold: 10000, …}
2:{metricavgcount: 2, instid: 1, metric: "Average Active Sessions", unit: "Active Sessions", threshold: 50, …}
[...]
```

When I try to exctract the array from the `$resource`Object, the return is just an empty / unfulfilled promise. What I tried:

```
$scope.dbData = $resource(url, {}, {
  query: {
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: function (data) { return data.items;},
  isArray: true
}});
```

So I think I just have to pass the $resource to the view and do the rest there.

In every Tutorial I can find, people just loop through the Array of Objects and it looks so easy:

```
<div ng-repeat="dbDat in dbData"> {{dbData.myVariable}} </div>
```

But how do I loop through an Array ( e.g. with `ng-repeat` (?)) within an $resource-object in my html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request is async operation, so you need to process data from request in its callback via *$promise* property.

Example from AngularJs [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/resource#resource-returns):

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId: '@id'});
User.get({userId: 123}).$promise.then(function(user) {
  // here you can assign your fetched data to $scope
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really had to get a bit more into how to handle promises...!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your code to the following:

```
$resource(url, {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        transformResponse: function (data) { return data.items; },
        isArray: true
    }
}).query(function (result) {
    $scope.dbData = result;
});
```